Exact regret of $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm for $k$-armed bandit
The $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm for $k$-armed bandit, tosses a coin with success probability $\epsilon$ at each round and does the following:

If not successful chooses the best arm till now, and
if successful chooses an arm randomly.

I want to prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n=\frac{\epsilon}{k}\sum_{i}\Delta_i
$$
where $\Delta_i$ is the suboptimality gap for arm $i$. I can see that the regret is bounded by the value on right since we could assume that at every stage the best arm till now is actually the best arm. But I can't see how I could rigorously prove that the left hand side bounds the right hand side. I have to somehow argue that as $n$ approaches infinity, the observed mean of every arm approaches its expected value and therefore eventually we get the linear bound on the right but I don't know how to do this. (I suspect there should be some use of laws of large numbers but I don't know how to spell this out.)

Under the $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm, the regret at time $n$ can be decomposed based on whether the MAB explores with probability $ϵ$ or exploits with probability $(1−ϵ)$.
Each time the MAB explores, it chooses an arm uniformly at random, so each arm $i$ is chosen with probability $1/k$. Then the expected cumulative regret from exploration over $n$ steps has this relation $R_n^{explore}/n=ϵ(1/k)∑^k_{i=1}Δ_i$.
During exploitation it chooses the arm with the highest observed mean reward so far. By the law of large numbers (LLN), as $n→∞$ the sample mean statistic for each arm will converge to the expected reward of that arm. This implies that with high probability the best recorded arm will converge to the true best arm asymptotically, meaning that the regret incurred during exploitation diminishes over time which can be expressed as $\text{lim}_{n→∞} R^{exploit}_n/n=0$.
Now combine the above two contributions of regret then you arrive at your goal.

Yeah, I understand all this. I don't know how to rigorously use LLN. I have to first say that each arm will be pulled enough times and then use LLN another time to say the mean statistic will converge to true mean.

Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4995528/iterative-use-of-law-of-large-numbers/4995608#4995608

@Navid For my above exploration relation to be rigorous you can invoke LLN to formally express the sample mean statistic as $N_i(n)/n$ following your notation where $n$ is the total pulls you're trying which goes to infinity in the limit. For the exploitation relation to be LLN-rigorous you can formally express the sample mean statistic as $(∑^{N_i(n)}{j=1}X{i,j})/N_i(n)$, where $X_{i,j}$ is the rewards observed each time the $i$-th arm is pulled. The point is if you can correctly express the sample mean statistic, you can easily use LLN formally. Hope this addresses your specific concern.

Yeah, thank you.
